# SQL Select MAX/MIN On Condition

Tags: sql, case

```
TABLE1
    STUDENT SUBJECT DATE
    1   ENGLISH 2/14/2021
    1   ENGLISH 4/24/2021
    1   ENGLISH 9/20/2022
    1   ENGLISH 11/14/2022
    1   HISTORY 12/15/2021
    1   HISTORY 3/3/2022
    1   HISTORY 3/12/2022
    2   ENGLISH 1/29/2021
    2   ENGLISH 4/20/2021
    2   ENGLISH 8/29/2022
    2   ART 3/24/2021
    3   ART 6/21/2019
```

TABLE2

```
STUDENT DATE    LAST_ENGLISH    ANY_HISTORY ANY_OTHER
1   2/14/2021   2/14/2021   1   0
1   4/24/2021   2/14/2021   1   0
1   9/20/2022   2/14/2021   1   0
1   11/14/2022  2/14/2021   1   0
2   1/29/2021   1/29/2021   0   1
2   4/20/2021   1/29/2021   0   1
2   8/29/2022   1/29/2021   0   1
2   3/24/2021   1/29/2021   0   1
```

I current have TABLE1 and wish to create TABLE2 where

LAST_ENGLISH = MAXIMUM(DATE) for each STUDENT when SUBJECT = ENGLISH

ANY_HISTORY = 1 for each STUDENT if SUBJECT ever equals to HISTORY, otherwise 0

ANY_OTHER = 1 for each STUDENT if SUBJECT ever equals ART or SCIECNE, otherwise 0

And then TABLE2 is one row for every time a STUDENT had ENGLISH with the other values that are constant for each STUDENT.

TABLE2 is restrict only to STUDENT who ever took ENGLISH

I try this:

```
 SELECT STUDENT, DATE,  case when SUBJECT = 'ENGLISH', MAX(DATE) else
 NULL as LAST_ENGLISH, case when SUBJECT = 'HISTORY', 1 else 0 as
 ANY_HISTORY, case when SUBJECT = 'ART' OR SUBJECT = 'SCIENCE', 1 else
 0 as ANY_OTHER FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY STUDENT
```

Comment: *LAST_ENGLISH = MAXIMUM(DATE)* but your expected output shows the min date ! also, for student 1 the expected output shows only rows for subject='english' but for student=2 shows rows for subject='english' or 'art', can you explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you? If I've understood your question correctly

```
SELECT
    t1.student,
    MAX(t1.date) AS date,
     (SELECT MAX(date) FROM TABLE1 AS t2 WHERE t2.student = t1.student GROUP BY t2.student HAVING SUM(t2.subject = 'ENGLISH')) AS last_english,
     (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'HISTORY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM TABLE1 AS t2 WHERE t2.student = t1.student) AS any_history,
     (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN subject IN ('ART', 'SCIENCE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM TABLE1 AS t2 WHERE t2.student = t1.student) AS any_other
FROM TABLE1 AS t1
GROUP BY t1.date,t1.student
HAVING last_english IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY student ASC
```

Here is a runable example, if something is wrong its very possible i'e misunderstood what you're looking for

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2478a1/52

I have now matched this exactly to the output you've provided

Comment: but wont this take the MAX by student and date?

Comment: I apologize I left out a detail but I add it to the Question. I want to include only STUDENT who ever have taken ENGLISH

Comment: sorry but this actually is not correct, did you see my TABLE2 desire output? THank you so much for your assistance

Comment: thank you again but I run it and it doesn't work as shown in TABLE2. 

ANY_HISTORY should equals to 1 for STUDENT==1 but in your example it equals to zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250154/discussion-between-bvowe-and-breezer).